# How to use FirebaseJobDispatcher

Tags: android, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am trying to use FirebaseJobDispatcher by following [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-)

But My question is that, How to set time interval for the dispatcher object like GCMNetworkManager (setPeriod).
Or please explain how FirebaseJobDispatcher works.

Answer (score 1):

Only started working with the Dispatcher a day ago so I could be wrong. I think for what you want to do, you have to set your job as **recurring** and choose a fitting **trigger**.

```
final Job.Builder builder = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setTag("myJob")
                .setService(myJobService.class)
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(59, 61));
```

Would give you a job which repeats roughly every minute.

How to start the job and set up the Dispatcher in general I would recommend you to have a look at the testapp which is available at the FirebaseJobDispatcher git repository (which you already linked).
Especially the classes [JobFormActivity](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/testapp/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/testapp/JobFormActivity.java) and [DemoJobService](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/testapp/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/testapp/DemoJobService.java).

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger roughly in 10 mins. **Note** - execution time may differ during doze mode after Marshmallow it depends on window available.

```
  Job myJob = mDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyJobService.class)
                .setTag(JOB_TAG)
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(600, 600))
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setReplaceCurrent(false)
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                .build();

    mDispatcher.schedule(myJob);
```